# "The given Closure has no parameters." in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Laravel trace each error but whenever I try to get the actual error this "The given Closure has no parameters." occurs

[image: Runtime error message]

[image: Error trace files]

I want the actual error behind this runtime error.

Can somebody help me to resolve this?

Comment: Check the following:
1: What route are you accessing.
2: Check the full trace log in storage/apps/logs/laravel.log 
3: Add a code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have registered custom exception handler, like this, with no arguments:
`app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function () {
           //....
        })->stop();
    }
```

But it should ave first argument with typehint:

```php
$this->reportable(function (MethodNotAllowedHttpException $e) {...
```

Comment: Yeah, I reverted that line to: 
`$this->reportable(static function (Throwable $e) { // });` 
Now everything is working again! :thumbs-up: